# Invalid input datetime format of value '1/01/1970'

Tags: magento2, error, products, format, datetime

i am trying to update products and all the products give me the same error and is

Invalid input datetime format of value '1/01/1970'

[image]

can someone help me. thanks

Comment: Check your available from dates also also check sale dates seems like you have input the value incorrectly

Comment: the dates are empty, i have tried dates and empty spaces and the error is the same

Comment: Id suggest going back through the form making sure you check the dates within advanced inventory also design as one of your date fields looks to be filled

Comment: sorry but i don't know where i can look for that. can you explain me more. thanks

Comment: Simply go through the form expanding all tabs/clicking all links within the form as one of your dates is filled

Comment: @micrgonz did you ever figure out what was causing this date issue? We are seeing this on a client of ours right now. Without getting to the cause of it we are just going to remove the invalid dates from the catalog_product_entity_datetime table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation I had under `advanced pricing` the `Special Price From` and `To` forms filled with `1/01/1970`. I cleared the fields and the error was gone. So, as said in the comments. Open all tabs and validate all your input fields.